# Jquery On Click event handler not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I don't understand why my code below does not work as expected. I want to create a dynamic table wherein user can add/delete rows. It does work on Jquery Click() function but the problem is that the Add function I want does not work on newly added elements in the DOM.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Hello</th>
        <th>world</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Hello</td>
        <td>world</td>
        <td class="add">add</td>
        <td class="remove">remove</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<script>
    $(".add").on('click','.add',function(e){    
        var parent = $(this).parent();      
        element = '<tr>';
        element += '<td>Hello</td>';
        element += '<td>world</td>';
        element += '<td class="add">add</td>';
        element += '<td class="remove">remove</td>';
        element += '</tr>';
        $(parent).after(element);
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: In order for you to understand why, `$(".add").on('click', '.add', function(e) {` is asking to attach a click event to every element with the `.add` class, and then trigger it on that element's children who also have the `.add` class. See how that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$(".add").on('click','.add',function(e){
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click','.add',function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(".add")` to `$("table")`,

```
<script>
    $("table").on('click','.add',function(e){    
        var parent = $(this).parent();      
        element = '<tr>';
        element += '<td>Hello</td>';
        element += '<td>world</td>';
        element += '<td class="add">add</td>';
        element += '<td class="remove">remove</td>';
        element += '</tr>';
        $(parent).after(element);
    }); 
</script>
```

In order to work click event for dynamically created element you need to use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) method

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

Your code says this when read out loud:

1. Find all the elements that have the class add.
2. Add a click event listener.
3. Listen for a click on a child element of .add that has a class of .add.

If you wrote a regular selector that would apply the events, it would have been

```
$(".add .add").click(function(){});
```

---

**What you need to do:**

The selector needs to be a parent element. It is a good rule of thumb to get as close to where the click event occurs. In your case, the tbody looks like a good place tolisten for the click.

```
$("table tbody").on('click','.add', function (e) {
```

also you do not have to wrap parent in a $() since it is already a jQuery object

```
$(parent).after(element);
```

should be

```
parent.after(element);
```

Final code

```
$("table tbody").on('click','.add', function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    var trow = $(this).closest("tr");      
    element = '<tr>';
    element += '<td>Hello</td>';
    element += '<td>world</td>';
    element += '<td class="add">add</td>';
    element += '<td class="remove">remove</td>';
    element += '</tr>';
    trow.after(element);
});
```